# Unable to set textarea width with CSS

Tags: css

I have attempted to use this CSS to set the width of my form elements:

```
input[type="text"], textarea { width:250px; }
```

If you look at this Firefox screenshot you'll see that the fields are not the same width. I get a similar effect in Safari.

[alt text http://screamingv.com/ss.png](http://screamingv.com/ss.png)

Are there any workarounds?

UPDATE: Thanks for the info so far. I've now made sure padding/margin/border on both elements are set the same. I was still having the problem. The original CSS I posted was simplified... I was also setting the height of the textarea to 200px. When I remove the height styling, the widths match. Weird. That makes no sense.

Browser bug?

Comment: Post the HTML and CSS that produces your example screenshot.

Comment: Have you checked for margins around the elements?

Comment: good luck styling input fields while preserving native l&f. If possible, set the border style to something acceptable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try removing padding and borders. Or try making them the same for both elements

```
input[type="text"],
textarea {
    width:250px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: none;
    }
```

Or:

```
input[type="text"],
textarea {
    width:250px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

INPUT and TEXTAREA elements often have some padding applied by the browser (varies by browser) and this can make things appear effectively wider than the assigned width.

UPDATE: also `box-sizing: border-box;` is a handy way to set widths that that padding and border will eat into rather than add onto. See: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 5):

This answer is three years late, but I'm posting it here just in case anyone else is trying to set the width in `em's` and not `pixels` and comes across this post (as I just did). Make sure the font-size is the same,

e.g.

```
input, textarea {
    font-size:12px; 
    width:20em; 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0 
}
```

otherwise the textarea may be a different size (true on FF12).

Answer (score 4):

Try border:0; or border: 1px solid #000;

Answer (score 3):

This is probably caused by different default margins on the `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements. Try using something like this.

```
input[type="text"], textarea { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width:250px; 
}
```

Comment: Padding and margin do not add width.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this kind of problem too, and this question was the first result of my googling. What finally worked for me was setting `box-sizing: content-box` for the textarea - Drupal 7 defaults this to `border-box` which causes the padding and border width to be subtracted from the size of the textarea.

Comment: This is at the moment the most future-proof solution, which is also least dangerous, as opposed to fiddling with margins and paddings. We are way past adhering to browsers, it's time to adhere to standards and force browser vendors to follow. Gotta start at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Set width 100% and then use max-width:

```
     textarea { 
          width:100%;
          max-width:250px;
     }
```

// removed margin and padding, you can add it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a user specific css overlay defined somewhere in your browser, because i just tested it and it works as expected: http://jsbin.com/exase/edit
(Tested on windows. Maybe Apple native widgets have some quirk?)

Answer (score 1):

you may use:

```
input[type="text"], textarea { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```