# CSS textarea widths differ from input widths in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I am setting the width of my text input's and text area using css:

```
input[type=text], 
input[type=file],
textarea {
    width: 305px;
}
```

For some reason in firefox the textarea width appears shorter:

[image]

Works fine in safari and chrome. How can I fix this?

**Solution:**

As explained here:
[Unable to set textarea width with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509529/unable-to-set-textarea-width-with-css)
adding:

```
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
```

does the trick.

Comment: After I answered, I realized we have a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509529/unable-to-set-textarea-width-with-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because the input tags and textarea tags have a different border by default. Try adding a border to your CSS to achieve the same widths.

```
input[type=text],
input[type=file],
textarea {
    width: 305px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Das2q/

Answer (score 0):

You could put all input fields into a `<div>` of a given width and make the width of the `<input>` and `<textarea>` fields 100%.

Comment: A lot of html would need to be rewritten to accommodate that.

Comment: I mean put all the fields into one big `<div>`, not put each field into one, although that may work too.

Comment: Did you check that link? Try making the padding and borders the same on both `<input>` and `<textarea>`.

Comment: Doing it this way would required me to separate the labels from the inputs into two separate divs. That kind of makes it bad style in my opinion since the two are closely related and belong together.

Answer (score 0):

What version of FF are you on? I tried it with 12.0 and it appears just fine for me.

Try this simple version to see if it is still throwing it off. It may have an issue from another part of your css definitions.

```
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
    input[type=text], 
    input[type=file],
    textarea {
        width: 305px;
    }   
</style>
</head>

<body>

<form>
    <input type="text" /><br/>
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```